# Node - exec child process side effects not visible in parent process

Tags: javascript, node.js, exec

```
   var exec = require('child_process').exec
    child = exec('export KEY="SOMEVALUE"', function(err, stdout, stderr){
      console.log(process.env.KEY)
    })
```

Does it print

```
SOMEVALUE
```

(or)

```
undefined
```

it prints undefined but doesn't the child process shell command effects propagate back to the parent process?

Comment: that will make KEY visible for child process but still in the callback function, it doesn't get defined....

Comment: [What do you want to achieve?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: exec('echo $KEY', {env: {'KEY': 'SOMEVALUE'}}), this will work... but it doesn't work when you print $KEY in the callback function because the child process context is lost during callback execution.+